# running scenerio file in tcl script in ns2

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, communication, wireless

I'm trying to run a scenario file in my `tcl` script (wireless communication using DSR). While running the `tcl` script in the terminal the file doesn't execute successfully. I am forced to stop the process after waiting for a long time.

```
set val(nn)           3                       ;# number of mobilenodes
set val(rp)        DSR                      ;# routing protocol
set val(x)            800
set val(y)            800
#set val(cp)             "../mobility/scene/cbr-3-test" 
set val(sc)             "scene-3-test" 
set val(stop)           5.0                 ;# simulation time
```

I am calling the file like this:

```
source $val(sc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The file "scene-3-test" is unknown!

Please upload "scene-3-test" to 'Google Docs', and show a link to the file in a new post.